# SyncTex on TeXworks

Tags: texworks, forward-inverse-search, pdfsync

I recently made the switch from Overleaf to TeXworks. In Overleaf, one can just double click a part of the compiled pdf, and it takes you to the relevant source code on the left. I wanted something similar on TeXworks, as finding a particular section within the code is a lot more painful. From my googling, I understand that synctex is something that shall allow me to do the same. However, I haven't found a clear answer on how to enable it (for a noob like me). I did try checking Edit>Preferences>Typesetting as some places suggested, but I couldn't find any option to sync. I have the latest version of TeXworks right now. If anyone can help me, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SyncTeX is always enabled in TeXworks: there is nothing to do. You need to Ctrl-click (Windows/Linux)/Cmd-click (macOS) to go from the source to the output and back.

Comment: That was... easier than I thought. Thank you!!